# What is wrong here? C language

Tags: c

Trying to make a square like this but there is some mistakes and I don't get them.

[image: square]

```
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return (0);
}

void    rush(x > 0 && y > 0)
{
    int w;
    int h;
    {
        if (w == 1 || w == x) && (h == 1 || h == y)
        {
            ft_putchar('o');
        }

        else if (w == 1 || w == x) && (h != 1 || h != y)
        {
            ft_putchar('|');
        }
        else if (w != 1 || w != x) && (h == 1 || h == y)
        {
            ft_putchar('-');
        }
        else if (w !=1 || w != x) && (h != 1 || h != y)
        {
            ft_putchar(' ');
        }
        h++;
        w++;
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    rush (5, 5);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: don't think that will compile (and certainly won't click that link)

Comment: `if (w == 1 || w == x) && (h == 1 || h == y)` huge error.

Comment: The link is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: Ok, code's included

Comment: We know where the link goes, but that is not the point.  Questions on SO cannot rely on possibly temporary links off-site.  I have removed the link and posted the code.  But you have not asked a question, merely demanded a solution.  We know what you want, but we don't know what you get - i.e. what is wrong with the code?  Don't expect anyone to take the trouble to compile and run your code to find out.

Comment: `void rush(x > 0 && y > 0)` - it's not even a declaration

Comment: This is just bad. No offense, but how long have you been writing C?

Comment: Since yesterday 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void    rush(x > 0 && y > 0)
```

That is not a valid C declaration of a function. (Are `x > 0` and `y > 0` supposed to be prerequisites to the function call?) A proper function call shows the types of the parameters, as in:

```
void    rush(int x, int y)
```

Neither the `rush` function nor the `main` routine has any loop. Some sort of loop is necessary in order to iterate through the rows and columns of the image and prepare characters to output to generate the image.

```
if (w == 1 || w == x) && (h == 1 || h == y)
```

An `if` statement must have one expression enclosed in parentheses. You can combine two expressions with `&&`, but the entire resulting expression must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
if ((w == 1 || w == x) && (h == 1 || h == y))
```

Fix the function declaration, fix the `if` statements, and write two `for` loops to iterate `h` and `w`, and then you will have made substantial progress toward the goal.